# how to use my existing .cpp code to write cuda code

Tags: cuda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use my existing .cpp code with cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348709/how-to-use-my-existing-cpp-code-with-cuda)

I have code in C++ and wanted to use it along with cuda.

Can anyone please help me?

I need some starting code to proceed for my code. I know how to do simple square program (using cuda and c++) for Windows(Visual Studio).

Is it sufficient to do the things for my program?

Here is the code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <fstream.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <conio.h>
# include <iostream.h>
    int key[64]={
        0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,
        0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,
        0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,
        0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,
        1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,
        1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
        1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
        1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
        };
class Des
{
 public:
  int keyi[16][48],
      total[64],
      left[32],
      right[32],
      ck[28],
      dk[28],
      expansion[48],
      z[48],
      xor1[48],
      sub[32],
      p[32],
      xor2[32],
      temp[64],
      pc1[56],
      ip[64],
      inv[8][8];

  char final[1000];
  void IP();
  void PermChoice1();
  void PermChoice2();
  void Expansion();
  void inverse();
  void xor_two();
  void xor_oneE(int);
  void xor_oneD(int);
  void substitution();
  void permutation();
  void keygen();
  char * Encrypt(char *);
};
void Des::IP() //Initial Permutation
{
    int k=58,i;
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
       ip[i]=total[k-1];
       if(k-8>0)  k=k-8;
       else       k=k+58;
    }
    k=57;
    for( i=32;i<64;i++)
    {
        ip[i]=total[k-1];
        if(k-8>0)   k=k-8;
        else        k=k+58;
    }
}
void Des::PermChoice1() //Permutation Choice-1
{
    int k=57,i;
    for(i=0;i<28;i++)
    {
        pc1[i]=key[k-1];
        if(k-8>0)    k=k-8;
        else         k=k+57;
    }
    k=63;
    for( i=28;i<52;i++)
    {
        pc1[i]=key[k-1];
        if(k-8>0)    k=k-8;
        else         k=k+55;
    }
    k=28;
    for(i=52;i<56;i++)
    {
        pc1[i]=key[k-1];
        k=k-8;
    }

}
void Des::Expansion() //Expansion Function applied on `right' half
{
    int exp[8][6],i,j,k;
    for( i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for( j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            if((j!=0)||(j!=5))
            {
                    k=4*i+j;
                exp[i][j]=right[k-1];
            }
            if(j==0)
            {
                k=4*i;
                exp[i][j]=right[k-1];
            }
            if(j==5)
            {
                k=4*i+j;
                exp[i][j]=right[k-1];
            }
        }
    }
    exp[0][0]=right[31];
    exp[7][5]=right[0];

    k=0;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    for(j=0;j<6;j++)
    expansion[k++]=exp[i][j];
}
void Des::PermChoice2()
{
    int per[56],i,k;
    for(i=0;i<28;i++) per[i]=ck[i];
    for(k=0,i=28;i<56;i++) per[i]=dk[k++];

    z[0]=per[13];z[1]=per[16];z[2]=per[10];z[3]=per[23];z[4]=per[0];z[5]=per[4];z[6]=per[2];z[7]=per[27];
    z[8]=per[14];z[9]=per[5];z[10]=per[20];z[11]=per[9];z[12]=per[22];z[13]=per[18];z[14]=per[11];z[15]=per[3];
    z[16]=per[25];z[17]=per[7];z[18]=per[15];z[19]=per[6];z[20]=per[26];z[21]=per[19];z[22]=per[12];z[23]=per[1];
    z[24]=per[40];z[25]=per[51];z[26]=per[30];z[27]=per[36];z[28]=per[46];z[29]=per[54];z[30]=per[29];z[31]=per[39];
    z[32]=per[50];z[33]=per[46];z[34]=per[32];z[35]=per[47];z[36]=per[43];z[37]=per[48];z[38]=per[38];z[39]=per[55];
    z[40]=per[33];z[41]=per[52];z[42]=per[45];z[43]=per[41];z[44]=per[49];z[45]=per[35];z[46]=per[28];z[47]=per[31];
}
void Des::xor_oneE(int round) //for Encrypt
{
 int i;
    for(i=0;i<48;i++)
        xor1[i]=expansion[i]^keyi[round-1][i];
}
void Des::xor_oneD(int round) //for Decrypt
{
 int i;
    for(i=0;i<48;i++)
        xor1[i]=expansion[i]^keyi[16-round][i];
}

void Des::substitution()
{
    int s1[4][16]={
        14,4,13,1,2,15,11,8,3,10,6,12,5,9,0,7,
        0,15,7,4,14,2,13,1,10,6,12,11,9,5,3,8,
        4,1,14,8,13,6,2,11,15,12,9,7,3,10,5,0,
        15,12,8,2,4,9,1,7,5,11,3,14,10,0,6,13
      };

    int s2[4][16]={
        15,1,8,14,6,11,3,4,9,7,2,13,12,0,5,10,
        3,13,4,7,15,2,8,14,12,0,1,10,6,9,11,5,
        0,14,7,11,10,4,13,1,5,8,12,6,9,3,2,15,
        13,8,10,1,3,15,4,2,11,6,7,12,0,5,14,9
       };

    int s3[4][16]={
        10,0,9,14,6,3,15,5,1,13,12,7,11,4,2,8,
        13,7,0,9,3,4,6,10,2,8,5,14,12,11,15,1,
        13,6,4,9,8,15,3,0,11,1,2,12,5,10,14,7,
        1,10,13,0,6,9,8,7,4,15,14,3,11,5,2,12
       };

    int s4[4][16]={
        7,13,14,3,0,6,9,10,1,2,8,5,11,12,4,15,
        13,8,11,5,6,15,0,3,4,7,2,12,1,10,14,9,
        10,6,9,0,12,11,7,13,15,1,3,14,5,2,8,4,
        3,15,0,6,10,1,13,8,9,4,5,11,12,7,2,14
       };

    int s5[4][16]={
        2,12,4,1,7,10,11,6,8,5,3,15,13,0,14,9,
        14,11,2,12,4,7,13,1,5,0,15,10,3,9,8,6,
        4,2,1,11,10,13,7,8,15,9,12,5,6,3,0,14,
        11,8,12,7,1,14,2,13,6,15,0,9,10,4,5,3
       };

    int s6[4][16]={
        12,1,10,15,9,2,6,8,0,13,3,4,14,7,5,11,
        10,15,4,2,7,12,9,5,6,1,13,14,0,11,3,8,
        9,14,15,5,2,8,12,3,7,0,4,10,1,13,11,6,
        4,3,2,12,9,5,15,10,11,14,1,7,6,0,8,13
       };

    int s7[4][16]={
        4,11,2,14,15,0,8,13,3,12,9,7,5,10,6,1,
        13,0,11,7,4,9,1,10,14,3,5,12,2,15,8,6,
        1,4,11,13,12,3,7,14,10,15,6,8,0,5,9,2,
        6,11,13,8,1,4,10,7,9,5,0,15,14,2,3,12
       };

    int s8[4][16]={
        13,2,8,4,6,15,11,1,10,9,3,14,5,0,12,7,
        1,15,13,8,10,3,7,4,12,5,6,11,0,14,9,2,
        7,11,4,1,9,12,14,2,0,6,10,13,15,3,5,8,
        2,1,14,7,4,10,8,13,15,12,9,0,3,5,6,11
       };
    int a[8][6],k=0,i,j,p,q,count=0,g=0,v;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=xor1[k++];
        }
    }

    for( i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        p=1;q=0;
        k=(a[i][0]*2)+(a[i][5]*1);
        j=4;
        while(j>0)
        {
            q=q+(a[i][j]*p);
            p=p*2;
            j--;
        }
        count=i+1;
        switch(count)
        {
        case 1: v=s1[k][q]; break;
        case 2: v=s2[k][q]; break;
        case 3: v=s3[k][q]; break;
        case 4: v=s4[k][q]; break;
        case 5: v=s5[k][q]; break;
        case 6: v=s6[k][q]; break;
        case 7: v=s7[k][q]; break;
        case 8: v=s8[k][q]; break;
        }

        int d,i=3,a[4];
        while(v>0)
        {
            d=v%2;
            a[i--]=d;
            v=v/2;
        }
        while(i>=0)
        {
            a[i--]=0;
        }

        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        sub[g++]=a[i];
    }
}

void Des::permutation()
{
    p[0]=sub[15];p[1]=sub[6];p[2]=sub[19];p[3]=sub[20];p[4]=sub[28];p[5]=sub[11];p[6]=sub[27];p[7]=sub[16];
    p[8]=sub[0];p[9]=sub[14];p[10]=sub[22];p[11]=sub[25];p[12]=sub[4];p[13]=sub[17];p[14]=sub[30];p[15]=sub[9];
    p[16]=sub[1];p[17]=sub[7];p[18]=sub[23];p[19]=sub[13];p[20]=sub[31];p[21]=sub[26];p[22]=sub[2];p[23]=sub[8];
    p[24]=sub[18];p[25]=sub[12];p[26]=sub[29];p[27]=sub[5];p[28]=sub[21];p[29]=sub[10];p[30]=sub[3];p[31]=sub[24];
}

void Des::xor_two()
{
 int i;
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        xor2[i]=left[i]^p[i];
    }
}

void Des::inverse()
{
    int p=40,q=8,k1,k2,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        k1=p;k2=q;
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            if(j%2==0)
            {
                inv[i][j]=temp[k1-1];
                k1=k1+8;
            }
            else if(j%2!=0)
            {
                inv[i][j]=temp[k2-1];
                k2=k2+8;
            }
        }
        p=p-1;q=q-1;
    }
}

char * Des::Encrypt(char *Text1)
{
  int i,a1,j,nB,m,iB,k,K,B[8],n,t,d,round;
  char *Text=new char[1000];
  strcpy(Text,Text1);
  i=strlen(Text);
  int mc=0;
  a1=i%8;
 if(a1!=0) for(j=0;j<8-a1;j++,i++) Text[i]=' '; Text[i]='\0';
 keygen();
  for(iB=0,nB=0,m=0;m<(strlen(Text)/8);m++) //Repeat for TextLenth/8 times.
  {
     for(iB=0,i=0;i<8;i++,nB++)
      {
         n=(int)Text[nB];
         for(K=7;n>=1;K--)
         {
          B[K]=n%2;  //Converting 8-Bytes to 64-bit Binary Format
          n/=2;
         } for(;K>=0;K--) B[K]=0;
       for(K=0;K<8;K++,iB++) total[iB]=B[K]; //Now `total' contains the 64-Bit binary format of 8-Bytes
      }
    IP(); //Performing initial permutation on `total[64]'
    for(i=0;i<64;i++) total[i]=ip[i]; //Store values of ip[64] into total[64]

    for(i=0;i<32;i++) left[i]=total[i]; //        +--> left[32]
                        // total[64]--|
    for(;i<64;i++) right[i-32]=total[i];//            +--> right[32]
    for(round=1;round<=16;round++)
    {
    Expansion(); //Performing expansion on `right[32]' to get  `expansion[48]'
    xor_oneE(round); //Performing XOR operation on expansion[48],z[48] to get xor1[48]
    substitution();//Perform substitution on xor1[48] to get sub[32]
    permutation(); //Performing Permutation on sub[32] to get p[32]
    xor_two(); //Performing XOR operation on left[32],p[32] to get xor2[32]
    for(i=0;i<32;i++) left[i]=right[i]; //Dumping right[32] into left[32]
    for(i=0;i<32;i++) right[i]=xor2[i]; //Dumping xor2[32] into right[32]
     }
    for(i=0;i<32;i++) temp[i]=right[i]; // Dumping   -->[ swap32bit ]
    for(;i<64;i++) temp[i]=left[i-32];  //    left[32],right[32] into temp[64]

    inverse(); //Inversing the bits of temp[64] to get inv[8][8]
    /* Obtaining the Cypher-Text into final[1000]*/
           k=128;   d=0;
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
          for(j=0;j<8;j++)
          {
            d=d+inv[i][j]*k;
            k=k/2;
          }
           final[mc++]=(char)d;
           k=128;   d=0;
        }
  } //for loop ends here
  final[mc]='\0';
  return(final);
}

void main()
{
 Des d1,d2;
 char *str=new char[1000];
 char *str1=new char[1000];
 clrscr();
 //strcpy(str,"Hi, This is snehal here.");
 cout<<"Enter a string : ";
      gets(str);
 str1=d1.Encrypt(str);
 cout<<"\ni/p Text: "<<str<<endl;
 cout<<"\nCypher  : "<<str1<<endl;
//   ofstream fout("out2_fil.txt"); fout<<str1; fout.close();
 cout<<"\no/p Text: "<<d2.Decrypt(str1)<<endl;
 getch();
}

void Des::keygen()
{
    PermChoice1();

    int i,j,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<28;i++)
    {
        ck[i]=pc1[i];
    }
    for(i=28;i<56;i++)
    {
        dk[k]=pc1[i];
        k++;
    }
    int noshift=0,round;
    for(round=1;round<=16;round++)
    {
        if(round==1||round==2||round==9||round==16)
            noshift=1;
        else
            noshift=2;
        while(noshift>0)
        {
            int t;
            t=ck[0];
            for(i=0;i<28;i++)
            ck[i]=ck[i+1];
            ck[27]=t;
            t=dk[0];
            for(i=0;i<28;i++)
            dk[i]=dk[i+1];
            dk[27]=t;
            noshift--;
        }
        PermChoice2();
        for(i=0;i<48;i++)
            keyi[round-1][i]=z[i];
    }
}
```

There are so many restrictions that I found.. like how to use d1.Encrypt() function in cuda. I don't know whether class is supported or not. But, I read in nVIDIA CUDA C programming guide 3.1(B.2.5 Restrictions) struct has some restrictions. So, I tried using class. Please help me to have some starting point for this program. I know the code is so large. But I'll be very much thankful if u could help me. Thanks!