# how to use my existing .cpp code to write cuda code

Tags: c++, c, cuda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use my existing .cpp code with cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348709/how-to-use-my-existing-cpp-code-with-cuda)

Hi all...Sorry for such a large program...
This program works well for VS2008. Now I m trying to write the same for CUDA. Please let me know how to write **global** and **shared** & other important things for this program. 
I started developing for main() and Keygen() but its not proper.Please help me.Thank You!